# Select random element from "non uniform" python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I have a python dictionary in which values are lists of integers:

```
key1 -> [1, 2, 3]
key2 -> [1, 2, 3, ... 17]
key3 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to select a random tuple(key, val) where val is a random value from the list of values (for example: key2, 8). The random selection must be uniform across all the values, so for example, this method is not uniform:

```
random_key = random.choice(d.keys())
random_val = random.choice(d[random_key])
```

because the lists are not of the same length.
I know the length of the concatenation of the lists, n, so my current approach is the following:

```
idx = np.random.randint(n)
c = 0
found = False

for k in D:
    for v in D[k]:
        if c == idx:
            found = True
            do_something_with_val(k, v);
            break
        c += 1
    if found:
        break
```

My question is: is there a better/faster method of doing this?

Comment: do you control setting of values in those lists?

Comment: Do you know what will be the maximum length of the lists? Or it is out of your control?

Comment: The maximum length of the lists is known and it does not change. However, the distribution of the elements across the lists does change.
For example: the element 5 can be removed from "key2" and a new element 1 can be added to "key3", but the maximum length of the lists is always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try (in Python 3—for Python 2, use `iteritems()`):

```
idx = random.randint(0, n)
for k, v in D.items():
    if idx < len(v):
        do_something_with_val(k, v[idx])
        break
    else:
        idx -= len(v)
```

Speed measuring:

```
def ref():
    idx = random.randint(0, n)
    c = 0
    found = False
    for k in D:
        for v in D[k]:
            if c == idx:
                found = True
                # do_something_with_val(k, v);
                break
            c += 1
        if found:
            break


def uut():
    idx = random.randint(0, n)
    for k, v in D.items():
        if idx < len(v):
            # do_something_with_val(k, v[idx])
            break
        else:
            idx -= len(v)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(timeit.timeit('ref()', setup="from __main__ import ref", number=1000))
    print(timeit.timeit('uut()', setup="from __main__ import uut", number=1000))
```

Results:

```
1.7672173159990052
0.011254642000494641
```

I checked distribution using small `D` like `{'key2': [3, 4, 5], 'key1': [0, 1, 2]}` and the distribution looks good for me:

```
0,166851
1,166141
2,166269
3,167094
4,167130
5,166515
```

Comment: I think it should be idx < len(v). However, I tried this approach and is slightly slower than mine.

Comment: @Frost, I've added speed measuring. Can you check it?

Comment: For speed, `iteritems()` instead of `items()` is appropriate.

Comment: @EOL Yes, you're right! But my example for python3.

Comment: I tried with `items()` using python 2. I'll try again with `iteritems()` and let you know.

Comment: I tried with iteritems() and indeed your method is faster :)

Answer (score 0):

You can build an helper "values" container and use it for the random choice...

```
import random


d = {1: [1, 2],
     2: [1, 2, 3, 4]}


values = [(k, v) for k, l in d.items() for v in l ]    
k,v = random.choice(values)
print (k, v)
```

This approach is very fast but takes more memory...
Have fun ;)

Comment: Actually, the dict has many updates, so I would  have to recompute `values` a lot of times, making it slower.

Comment: @Frost Maybe consider not using a dict but a "values" like container instead to meet your needs?